# Error trying to upload data using Mapbox API

Tags: geojson, convert, mapbox, batch, epsg

I'm using the Mapbox API and I'm trying to upload my GeoJSON but I'm getting the following error:

> bounds west value must be between -360 and 360

My GeoJSON looks like this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
  "crs":
    {"type":"name",
      "properties":
       {"name":"EPSG:27700"}
     },
  "features":
    [{"type":"Feature",
      "id":1,
      "geometry":
        {"type":"MultiLineString",
          "coordinates":[[ 
             [343131.34379999992,566499.875],
             [343129.625,566502.3125],
             [343126.1875,566505.9375],
             [343124.6875,566507.3125],
             [343122.875,566508.125],
        ...
```

So I noticed that this is in BNG and I assume that Mapbox needs that in lat long values.
I did a bit of research and I think that I've to convert from EPSG:27700 to EPSG:4326.

Is there anyway to convert the file in a batch process? My file is about 500mb and contains few millions of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the ogr2ogr suggestion!

Finally I converted the file using an online service called [MyGeoData](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/) (I'm not sure if I'm allow to post the link here - so, please edit my answer if needed).

I suppose that ogr2ogr is the most complete long-term solution but for a one-time conversion the online solution was more suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Correct you'll need to convert this to EPSG:4326.ogr2ogr can batch reproject.

Comment: Please elaborate on this. Perhaps show some code or examples. Otherwise, your answer risks being deleted.

Comment: That's a bit harsh. Someone else is free to submit a more elaborate answer if they like or edit mine. But absent any other answer, my answer points the asker towards the solution. If you don't like it use the downvote button.

Comment: Why will OP need to convert this to EPSG:4326? How can ogr2ogr batch reproject?